# Secured path/folder in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I created a secure path in in my web-application.

like mention in this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648341.aspx

when i use the below config for secure my files:

```
<location path="Secure">
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="error.html">
      </customErrors>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

the below files are not accessable without loign:

```
my host link /secure/xyz/01.doc    
my host link /secure/xyz/01.docx    
my host link /secure/xyz/01.xls    
my host link /secure/xyz/01.xlsx
```

but the below files are still accessable without login:

```
my host link /secure/xyz/01.pdf    
my host link /secure/xyz/01.txt    
my host link /secure/xyz/01.png
```

---

any idea about such a behaviour?
why other than office document files are still accessable?
i need to secure them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution.

After login, when click to download on the file having formate .pdf .png .txt,

Browser didnt download - but it shown in the same tab
(and browser cached it, i think so... Correct me if i Wrong!!!)
in case of .doc .xls it open the dialog to download (without caching).

After Logout, on browsing the download link of .pdf .png .txt
It opens it / load it from cache.
on the other hand, while surfing .doc .xls redirect me to login

Answer (score 0):

While your `web.config` secured your web pages and *certain* files, the PDFs, like many other static files, are being served up *directly* by IIS.

You can force these other static files to go through the ASP.NET pipleline by adding `StaticFileHandler` entries in your web.config, in the handlers section.

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="PDFHandler" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" path="*.pdf" verb="GET"  />
    <add name="PNGHandler" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" path="*.png" verb="GET"  />
    <add name="TXTHandler" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" path="*.txt" verb="GET"  />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

I would guess though you already have something similar to this for your other office document types. Either in the `web.config` or in IIS.